# Storing object in Ehcache for long periods

Tags: java, ehcache

In my application, data in a table is flushed and repopulated once in a day(by a batch) and then never changed. So I plan to pull entire data from the table and put it in second level cache(Ehcache) at end of batch. So my requirement is that data lies there in cache for next 24 hrs after which batch would clear the cache and populate it with fresh data.
My concern is that would Ehcache be able to keep data for this long.
And what other concerns I must take care of for my requirement?

Comment: What makes you think that it wouldn't?

Comment: Because I have rarely seen configuration parameters set to such large value.Most of the times its just several minutes. And it is possible that if objects are unused for considerable time then cache may get rid of them,irrespective of parameters set....just my concern.

Comment: Have you seen this _get rid of them,irrespective of parameters set_ documented anywhere? Given that [the documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/data-life.html) explicitly states that items have "_infinite lifetime_" **by default**, maybe it would help if you read that rather than asked unclear questions on this site?

Comment: What do you mean by unclear question.Question is quite obvious, and arose out of my concern.

Answer (score 0):

There must be parameter in ehcache named time-to-live where you can set how long cache entry should be in the cache before it is evicted from cache. Please check the ehcache docs

Comment: This link should help http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/data-life.html

Comment: Thanks for reply.I am aware of that configuration parameter, but my concern is that I have rarely seen this parameter set to values greater than several minutes. 24 hr is too big a value in comparison. So I am concerned if cache would complain.

Comment: Even though I have never with such a high TTL value, I don't think that should cause any issues. Said that, It may be a good idea to try it out with some prototype.